# URL like string parsing in python

Tags: python, string-parsing

I need to parse a string which is more or less a url.. for example i have a string which is a URL

```
tempString = "?var1=somevalue1&var2=somevalue2&var3=somevalue3"
```

i need to parse the string `tempString` and get the value of `var1 var2` and `var3` from it. What's the best way to get the value.

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse?  It has the parse query string.  What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs).

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick way, but you'd need to prepend a host and path to your example string.

```
import urlparse

scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit( url )
parameters = urlparse.parse_qs( query )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use urlparse. For example, [see this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/python-urlparse-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Well if it were really a URL ... or a URL query string (which looks closer to your example) then I suppose you could use the urlparse module's .parse_qsl() function.

For example:

```
import urlparse
... 
qry = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(tempString))
## parse_qsl returns a tuple of tuples suitable for instantiating or updating a dictionary
```